# Applying Bayes theorem to a simple problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayes-theorem

When a test for steroids is given to soccer players, 98%
of the players taking steroids test positive and 12% of the
players not taking steroids test positive. Suppose that 5%
of soccer players take steroids. What is the probability
that a soccer player who tests positive takes steroids?

The way I approached this was drawing a tree of possibilities then calculating like so:
$+$ = "testing positive", 
$S =$ "taking steroids",
$\frac{P(+|S) \times P(S)}{P(+|S) \times P(S) + P(+|\neg S) \times P(\neg S)}$
$=\frac{.95 \times .98}{.95 \times .98 + .05 \times .12} = .9936$.

However, others are saying the answer is $.3006$. Was I wrong in my methodology?

Comment: I think you just plugged in the numbers wrong or mixed up some of the probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to know the probability that a soccer player who tests positive takes steroids, i.e. $P(S|+)$.

By Bayes Theorem we have: $$P(S|+)=\frac{P(+|S)P(S)}{P(+|S)P(S)+P(+| \neg S)P(\neg S)}$$

We are given $P(S)=0.05$, $P(+|S)=0.98$, $P(+|\neg S)=0.12$, $P(\neg S)=0.95$.

Plugging them in gives $P(S|+)=\frac{0.98\times 0.05}{0.98\times 0.05+0.12\times 0.95} \approx 0.3006$.

I hope that helps.